# In unity, how would I make an object always slowly move toward another object, I am a complete beginner

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a game where someone will control a character collecting various collectibles for a coursework assignment. This also needs another sprite moving toward the player which needs to be avoided. How would I program a new object to slowly follow a moving character?

I have not tried yet, I am not sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your 'sprite' to follow the player like a physical person or an animal would do, you should check some tuto about navmesh, this will create a "AI pathfinding" based on your map and then you can assign a navmeshagent to your 'sprite' so that he will follow the player.

If you want your 'sprite' to go throught walls like a ghost, put :

```
transform.position += (playerposition - transform.position).normalized * speed*Time.deltaTime;
```

in its Update function, where speed is a float and playerposition a Vector3 of the position of the player (can be replaced by player.transform.position where player is the GameObject of the player)